# Is AddTimestampToStaticLinks slow?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4mvc

T4MVC has a setting AddTimestampToStaticLinks which adds to the url file's last change time:

> /Content/nerd.jpg?2009-09-04T12:25:48

It is very convenient during development as files which are often changed are not cached by the browser. But should I keep it for production? How slow is it? I even not sure how it works. Who does make the magic of converting "/Content/nerd.jpg?2009-09-04T12:25:48" to "/Content/nerd.jpg"? Some of IIS modules?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Should I keep it for production?

Yes.  It gives your users the same benefits you get in development.

> How slow is it?  I'm not even sure how it works.

I don't have timings, but it's probably negligibly fast for your purposes.  It checks the last modified date on the actual file, generates a hash of the tick count difference, and uses string concatenation to append it to the url.  You can inspect yourself because t4 templates are just text files.  The code for it looks like this in the version I have:

```
static DateTime CenturyBegin=new DateTime(2001,1,1);
public static string TimestampString(string virtualPath) {
    if (!HostingEnvironment.IsHosted) return string.Empty;
    string filePath = HostingEnvironment.MapPath(virtualPath);
    return Convert.ToString((System.IO.File.GetLastWriteTimeUtc(filePath).Ticks-CenturyBegin.Ticks)/1000000000,16);            
}
```

If it is not fast enough for your purposes, you can modify the method which appends the time stamp to something fast enough for your.  Less precise but faster methods would be like the assembly build number or something you change manually in the build process.  Sticking with the default will make it so that only files which have been modified will be cache invalidated however.

> Who does make the magic of converting "/Content/nerd.jpg?2009-09-04T12:25:48" to "/Content/nerd.jpg"?

With HTTP, you can append a query string to any request.  Most server implementations simply disregard the query string for static files, however they treat different query strings as a separate requests, hence getting the updates as soon as they are made.

Even if you don't change the file, you can force browsers to reload the content by simply changing the url + query string to something the client does not have cached.

Comment: Good answer. Another important point is that the time stamp is calculated in a static field, which means it only happens once per appdomain. So it really cannot have any perf impact, other than a very small one when your app first starts (or gets reset).

Comment: @David Ebbo, why not to enable it by default then? :)

Comment: Not sure, it probably could be. :) The feature was contributed by someone else, and at the time we just wanted to be safe with it and not break anyone.

Comment: FYI Interesting thread: http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/workitem/7163 where someone suggests that caching don't work when using query string. I have not investigated yet...